# Find all allowed characters defined a regex pattern using java

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract all allowed characters defined in regex pattern using java program.
For example if my pattern is

> **^[A-F0-5+=\\*/]{1,10}-[a-f]{1,10}$**

it should give me output as

> **A,B,C,D,E,F,0,1,2,3,4,5,+,=,\,*,/,-,a,b,c,d,e,f**

https://regex101.com/ does return similar content in explanation div, but I'm looking for java program to get those.

Comment: Do you need to account for lookahead (for example `(?!a)a`)? Or repeat (for example `[abc]{0}`)?

Comment: What's your character set? If the pattern is ```.*```, how many characters will you output?

Comment: This seems like a potentially unbounded problem, because even in your example there are multiple character classes.  If the pattern has a `.*` anywhere, does that mean we should report all characters?

Comment: I'm not concerned about number of occurrences. I want to get it as a set of all allowed characters within entire pattern which shouldn't contain duplicates.

Comment: @Tim Biegleisen, agreed. Well I can say that I will extract allowed characters if pattern doesn't contains` .*` or `.+`

Comment: you need to write a parser for regex, here is a link to a tutorial on writing a such a parser for simple math, this can give you a base to start from http://cogitolearning.co.uk/2013/04/writing-a-parser-in-java-the-tokenizer/

Comment: It is not clear what you need. https://regex101.com/r/5n5lWP/1 shows what kind of match you can expect with your regex.  Please add all necesary details to help potential answerers to the *question body*, not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this pattern:**

```
[A-Fa-f0-5]|\+|\=|\\|\*|\/|\-
```

You can test it [online](https://www.regextester.com/97778)

[image]

Another [Java Regular Expression Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

[image]